# exclude fields on post, put request in epilogue

Tags: express, sequelize.js, epilogue

I am using expressjs with sequalize ORM. My user model is some what like

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
 var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    userName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: DataTypes.Boolean
    }
   })
  }
```

but I dont want to allow the request to set isAdmin to be set to true or false on POST/PUT. But i want isAdmin on get request.

I know about excludeAttributes property but it removes the fields on `GET` request only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `readOnlyAttributes`. This feature is yet not included in published release. However you can use it by changing your epilogue version to `dchester/epilogue#master` in `package.json`.
Sample code might look like

```
var rest = require('epilogue')
var userResource = rest.resource({
   model: DB.User,
   readOnlyAttributes: ['isAdmin']
});
```

See this [Pr](https://github.com/dchester/epilogue/pull/131).

Comment: oh i didn't notice this. Works perfectly. Hope epilogue publishes this ASAP